# Can pushdown automata be without epsilon transitions?

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

Are pushdown automata without $\varepsilon$-transitions as powerful as those with them? Intuitively, if we need to make such a transition, we could just add the letters on the next transition we take, but I'm not convinced by that reasoning.

Comment: @D.W. Yes, I agree. The present question is perhaps better formulated, but the final line of the linked question is "Is there a canonical epsilon-free form for PDAs", which is what we have here.